# Is there a way to highlight a specific line within a codeblock using GitHub's markdown?

Tags: markdown

I have a code block where I'd like to highlight a line for instructional purposes while preserving the other lines for context. I suspect there is no real way of doing this but wanted to see if perhaps somebody had a workaround.

```
<div>
  <p>Highlight this line</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe use the Google search work around, it keeps it in the url.